# Weights in Portfolio Attribution when considering Currency

Tags: currency, performance-evaluation

I'm performing a simple Portfolio attribution with the Brinson 1985 model where returns are decomposed into both an **allocation** component and a **selection**.  Using the formula, I first did the attribution with all assets denominated in my local currency (CAD) and I noted that a lot of my assets are in USD.  My question is, if I want to extract out the currency effect and only decompose the returns based on equity moves.  How would I go about calculating the correct weight? I should also note that I am doing this on a multi-period basis so any help on that would be appreciated.

For example, If Stock A is in US Dollar and Stock B is in CAD in a two-asset portfolio, the non-equity return for A is simply just the stock return in US dollar.  However, the Weight of the stock $W_A$ is dependent on the exchange rate $W_A = \frac{Val_{A}*USDCAD}{(Val_{A}*USDCAD + Val_{B})}$.  Would it still be correct that I use the weight given there or do I need to calculate it from a different perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the base `ccy` of the your portfolio is `CAD`, then it makes sense to use the asset weights in `base` too (`= CAD`) according to your described formula.

Comment: But Let's say that for one period no returns were generated by either Assets but rather the fx rate against CAD appreciated by 1% and thus the % weighting of A increases for the next period.  From the Brinson formula, this can state an over or under performance in terms of allocation or selection effect right?

Comment: @KevinPei: sure, in this case your portfolio attribution should disclose the `currency effect` attributable to `CAD` appreciation. It will theoretically be misleading/incorrect to isolate any `currency effect` from your portfolio attribution, in particular if you have lots of off-base (`ccy`) securities. This is a frequent situation while performing portfolio attribution on funds with several `share classes` (for various purposes such as `hedgding`). `PS:` Always bear in mind the purpose of  `portfolio attribution`.